# error in playing a sound in alarm in android application

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an android application in which I have to play an alarm and set the reminder.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @ thelper,,below are my 2 java classes code ,,,http://pastebin.com/CJwKhf6M,http://pastebin.com/PeL0KhLN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) doesn't actually ring an audible alarm. If you schedule an alarm the alarm manager will notify your app at the set alarm time by starting the `PendingIntent` you've provided (in your case the AlarmService). It doesn't do anything more. If you want sound, your AlarmService should play that when the service is started. You can use the android [mediaplayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

To play sound in notification you have to set the url of the sound file as below

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean isSound = pref.getBoolean("sound", true);
String soundUri;
if(isSound) {
    soundUri = pref.getString("Ringtone", String.valueOf(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)));
}
notification.sound = Uri.parse(soundUri);
```

For set notification sound you can use `RingtonePreference`

Here is a demo xml for Preference screen

```
    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Vibrate"
        android:key="Vibrate" android:defaultValue="true"></CheckBoxPreference>
    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Notification Sound"
        android:key="Sound" android:defaultValue="true"></CheckBoxPreference>
    <RingtonePreference android:title="Ringtone"
        android:key="Ringtone" android:dependency="Sound" android:summary="Select Ringtone"
        android:ringtoneType="notification" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Synchronized Task Notification">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Notify for new synchronized task"
        android:key="syncNotification" android:defaultValue="true"></CheckBoxPreference>
    <ListPreference
    android:title="Check for Synchronized tasks after every..."
        android:key="syncTime"
        android:dependency="syncNotification"
        android:defaultValue="300000"
        android:entries="@array/syncCheckTimeNames"
        android:entryValues="@array/syncCheckTimeValues" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```